# How To Reboot a PC inside snap app (created with Flutter) on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: flutter, dart, ubuntu, snapcraft

I have an Ubuntu 22.04 on my PC, and also i have a **snapped** Linux app that created with Flutter. I have also a button for rebooting the OS in my Flutter app.

I tried two different methods:

**method 1:**

```
await Process.run("reboot", []);
```

message:

```
flutter: Running in chroot, ignoring request.
```

**method 2:**

```
await Process.run('sudo', ['reboot']);
```

message:

```
flutter: >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 54 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 54
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

please show me how to run a command in Flutter for Rebooting the PC.